# Integral with respect to a restricted measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $\nu=h^n\lambda$ with $\lambda$ **the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$ restricted to the square $(0,h^{-1})$ and $h \in \mathbb N$** show that if $f$ is integrable with respect to $\nu$ then
> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f d \nu = h^n \int_{(0,h^{-1})^n} f dx$$
> First for a indicator function $\chi_A$ with $A- \nu$-measurable we have
> $$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \chi_A d \nu=\nu(A)=h^n \lambda(A \cap (0,h^{-1})^n)=h^n \int_{\mathbb{R^n}} \chi_{A\cap (0,h^{-1})^n}(x) dx $$
> $$=h^n\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \chi_{A}(x) \chi_{(0,h^{-1})^n}(x)dx=h^n \int_{(0,h^{-1})^n}\chi_{A}(x)dx$$
> and then i try to extend to any tipe of function, is these correct?
> any hint or help i will be very grateful

Comment: You only need look that a supremum and infimum of two families coincides and the work is done